# Trying to do a basic Selenium(Java) (To check if the title of a webpage) but the part of the code the checks the title is not running

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
public class WorkingWithChrome {

    ChromeDriver driver;
    
    String url = "https://www.alfasoft.pt/";
    
    public void invokeBrowser() {
        
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\fabio\\eclipse-workspace\\libs\\chromedriver.exe");
        
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    driver.get(url);
    
    
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        WorkingWithChrome wc = new WorkingWithChrome();
        
        wc.invokeBrowser();
        
        //wc.closeBrowser();
}
    
    
    public void TitleTest() throws Exception {
        
    String Url = "https://www.alfasoft.pt/";
    
    String TituloEsperado = "Alfasoft";
    
    String TituloAtual = "";
    
    driver.get(Url);
    
    TituloAtual = driver.getTitle();
    
    if (TituloAtual.contains(TituloEsperado)) {
        
        System.out.println("Titulo Correto!");
        
    } else {
    
        System.out.println("Titulo Errado!");

    }
    
    driver.quit();
    
    }
    
}
```

The page open's but I think that the part of the code that is suposed to check the title is not working because the webpage never closes. I just started using selenium, trying to learn it to use it on the current company that Im working at.

Comment: "_I think that the part of the code that is suposed to check the title is not working_", probably because in the code you showed, `TitleTest()` is never called. So you wouldn't know if it is working.

Comment: I don't see anything calling that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently in the `main` method you only invoking `wc.invokeBrowser();` but not invoking the `TitleTest()` method where you calling the `driver.quit();`
To invoke `TitleTest()` just put it in `main()` method as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    WorkingWithChrome wc = new WorkingWithChrome();
        
    wc.invokeBrowser();

    wc.TitleTest();
}
```

BTW, it's a convention in JAVA to give methods names starting with lowercase so it should be named `titleTest()` rather than `TitleTest()`

Comment: And how do I invoke the 'TittleTest()' method ? (I'v been programing for a very short time)